# Python Server and Java Client: Server recieves message but Client doesn't receive reply

Tags: java, python, sockets, server, client

I made a python server and a java client. My problem is simple:
The server receives the message from client, but the client doesn't get the reply.

Java Client:

```
package fgd;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;



public class fdassd {


        public static void main(String[] args){





              new Thread(){
               public void run(){
                while (true)
                {
                 try {Socket socke=new Socket("censored",1977);  

                    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(socke.getOutputStream());
                    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socke.getInputStream());

                    dout.writeUTF("Heey");
                    dout.flush();

                    String str = din.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(str);



                    dout.close();  
                    socke.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    } 




                try {
                    Thread.sleep(17000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
               }
              }.start();

}
}
```

Python Server:

```
            hosto = '0.0.0.0'
            porto = 1979
            soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            print 'Socket created!'

            try:
                    soc.bind((hosto, porto))
            except socket.error as e:
                print(e)
                    sys.exit()

            print 'Socket bind complete'

            soc.settimeout(30)
            soc.listen(10)

            print 'Listening...'

            timeout = 8

            timeout_start = time.time()

            while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
                try:
                        conn, addr = soc.accept()
                    if addr[0] != opip:
                        conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                        conn.close()
                    else:
                        msg = conn.recv(1024)
                        print ('--------------------------------------')
                        print (msg)
                        conn.send((playername).encode('UTF-8'))
                        print ('Success! The following command has been                             sent to: ' + opip + ':' + playername )
                        print ('--------------------------------------')
                        soc.close()
                        break 
                except socket.timeout as e:
                    print(e,': Server not online or wrong ip')
                    soc.close()
                    break




        else:
```

I've seen a very similar question where the answer was to add to lines before conn.send (Link: [Socket Java client - Python Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266026/socket-java-client-python-server?rq=1)). 
But I can't use the solution in that question, because

```
conn.send(len(message_to_send).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
```

doesn't seem to work in python 2.x .That means I need another solution to send the message with UTF-8 but I can't figure out what to do.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line, before you send the `playername`. This should work in both python2 and 3:

```
conn.send(struct.pack(">H", len(playername)))
```

This line will prefix the length of the player name to the message, as is required by the java `DataInputStream#readUTF` method.  It's encoded as a two-byte integer, hence the `'H'` in the `struct.pack` call.

You will also need an `import struct` statement.

See [Python 2,3 Convert Integer to "bytes" Cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043886/python-2-3-convert-integer-to-bytes-cleanly) for more information.